# Set defualt selected option- Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to add default selected option if the User role is "Supplier-Admin". Below is the code which I am working on.

When I use supplier[0] or [1] etc, it works. The company name of that element gets selected by default.

But when I use supplier[currentCompany], no option isn't getting selected as default.

```js
$scope.supplierRole = function() {

  var currentUser;
  if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {

    currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    console.log("Received", currentUser);
  } else {
    console.log("Not received");
  }
  var currentCompany = currentUser[0].company;
  if (currentUser[0].role == "Supplier-Admin") {
    $scope.newUser.company = $scope.supplier[currentCompany];
    return false;       
  } else if (currentUser[0].role == "Buyer-Admin") {
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="supplierRole()">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Company</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine }">
    <select class="form-control" 
            name="addCompany" placeholder="Select Company" 
            ng-options="company.name for company in supplier" 
            ng-model="newUser.company" 
            ng-required="true">
    </select>

    <span class="help-block"        
          ng-show="addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine">
      Your Company is required.
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, your dropdown is set to `newUser.company`, but your javascript sets `newUser` to `$scope.supplier[currentUser[0].company]`;   does that mean the dropdown would be set to `$scope.supplier[currentUser[0].company].company`?  seems like a typo to me.

Comment: Oh yeah. Its supposed to be newUser.company in js file too. I updated the code now.

Comment: But still no default option is getting selected :(. The list options gets displayed. So that works well.

Comment: it is a bit difficult to diagnose why your dropdown isn't selecting anything without seeing some sample data, but the first step would probably be to log out `$scope.newUser.company` and verify that it's actually set to a valid element from the list.

Comment: also, is `company` an object or a string?  That changes how `ng-repeat` works, and how it identifies which item is which in the list.....

Comment: @Claies Okay so far I have got it partially working. When I user array element value like  "$scope.newUser.company = $scope.supplier[0];" or [1] or [2], it works. The default option of that element is selected. But no option is selected by default if I use "$scope.supplier[currentUser[0].company];"

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check

Comment: well that would suggest that `currentUser[0].company` isn't returning an index that can be found in `supplier`.  does `company` have an integer representing the index, or have an object? again, it's very difficult to troubleshoot this without some data, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: When I add currentUser[0].company to watch while debugging, It does show that data. Also displays on the console window.

Comment: right, so if `currentUser[0].company` returns data, then how could you use it in place of an array index in the `supplier` array?  In other words, `supplier[0]` and `supplier[currentUser[0].company]` can't possibly be equivalent.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is when a user logins i.e current user, by default the listbox should display the company of which the current user belongs to. The supplier array has a list of companies. but I need to display a default option of which the current user's company is. So that is the reason why I used supplier[currentUser[0].company] which isn't working. I don't know if this is the correct way to do. I'm new to Angular JS.

Comment: it seems like what you want is you want to find the index of `currentUser[0].company` in the `supplier` array, and then use that, not the company itself.  This is a pretty generic JavaScript process.

Comment: Yes. I need the Index of that. How do I do that? Sorry I couldn't explain it well.

Comment: seems like we are making this harder than it really should be.  Would `$scope.supplier.findIndex(currentUser[0].company);` give you the index to set the item?

Comment: Unfortunately still not working :(. I debugged and in the watch, the `$scope.supplier` displays the array list and the `currentUser[0].company` also displays the company name. But `$scope.supplier.findIndex(currentUser[0].company);` shows that its not available.

Comment: well at this point, I'm not sure how to help. Without having *data to examine*, I'm just making guesses, and bad ones at that.  Try to post some data or a [mcve].